# VBA: Surprising least squares result

Tags: excel, regression, vba

When running the code:

```
    x(0) = 1200
    x(1) = 1800
    x(2) = 2200
    y(0) = 64
    y(1) = 45
    y(2) = 84
    v = Application.LinEst(y, x, True, True)
```

I get v(1,1)= 1.59 (k-value) and v(1,2)= 36.74. How can this be a least squares regression?

y(0) approx = x(0)*k + m
64 approx = 1200* 1.59 + 36.74 ?????

The curve seems to differ a lot from the average relationship between x and y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other response shows, I think you omitted the E-02 exponent from the k-value:

1200*0.0159+36.74 = 55.82

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Because your three data points are almost random, having a R2 of only 0.17. Your data doesn't really suppprt a linear trend (and delving deeper into stats, 3 points doesn't give you enough degrees of freedom for a valid trend)

[image]